# Task row and grid row are not aligning properly when scrolled vertically in the dhtmlx gantt chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

Iam using dhtmlx gantt chart version 4.2.1 for our project.

When the scrollbar is moved vertically, then the task row and grid row are not getting alligned properly. Please see the below screenshot.

[image: Gantt Issue]

I have looked into dhtmlx forum, but didn't find anything there. Even posted in dhtmx forum, but did not get any response from them.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this had been fixed already (most probably starting from 4.2.4), you can download the latest release here https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/download.shtml